# How to set 100% height to an animation div

Tags: html, css, animation

I am messing around with CSS animations because they're pretty kick ass.

I am trying to make a nav bar on the left hand side of the page. I want the bar to take up 100% of the height of the page, but when I set that property for the height, my bar no longer appears on the page. Does CSS animations not work with % based height and width?

My CSS:

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden
}
div {
-webkit-animation:myfirst 4s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
font-size: .2px;
padding-left: 5px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */{
    0% {
        background:orange;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    100% {
        background:orange;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
        opacity: 0.7;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sidebar_left.css">
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dKmy/)

Answer (score 1):

to set an elements height as 100% page height - its direct parent should be the body element and the `body` & `html` elements will also need to have a height of 100%... if your element is further nested in the dom you can also just continue the chain of 100% height for all of its parents and parents parents ... etc

Comment: `html` element needs to be `100%` as well.

Comment: Aha! The body & the HTML element needs to be set to 100% width & height. Thank you guys!

Comment: updated the answer, i did it in my test but forgot to mention it here - must be time to grab that coffee